# Delphi package install error - DCU not found

Tags: delphi, package, pascal

I am trying to install a Delphi package from the VST SDk, my problem is that it says a .dcu is missing.
The .dcu is not missing, and before installing the package, it doesn't exist, but is created by the 
IDE during the installation, so it's not precompiled from a former version of Delphi. The .pas file doesn't appear to be incomplete. All the other files appear to be installing just fine, this however is giving me a great load of trouble. I hope someone might help me :) 
Im using Delphi 2010 btw.

Thanks in advance :D
[Image showing my files and errors](http://postimage.org/image/viz7mah51/)
[Here's the SDK - im using 1.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/files/Source%20Code/)

Comment: Nice to see that there are more VST developers here that you Delphi. If you run into problems, make sure to come back here.

Comment: I assume that you are interested in VST developement too, since you post this. I would really love to chat ideas, concepts, code etc., my skype is Tramper-6000, if you are interested :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the compiler cannot find the source files, or the dcu files.

There are several ways to solve this.

1. You can add the paths that contain the .pas files to your library, via `/tools/options/EnvironmentOptions/DelphiOptions/Library/LibraryPath`
2. You can add the paths to the search path of the project.
   In the project options (<kbd>ctrl+shift+f11</kbd>)
3. You can add each file that you need to the project. <kbd>shift+f11</kbd>

Note that you can also point to the folder that contains the .dcu files, but that means you wouldn't be able to step through code when you're debugging.

I usually use method 1, because that settles it for all future projects that you use in this IDE. It's convenient if you create many projects that use the same library.
Some other people like to specify this per project, so that they have full control over the dependencies of the project.